# I can't get the alignment right of the loader and the text that is supposed to be left of the loader

Tags: html

This is my first html test file, please don't show hate.

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="7; url='http://127.0.0.1:8887/test.html'" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
        .loader {
            border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
            border-radius: 50%;
            border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
            width: 120px;
            height: 120px;
            -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
            /* Safari */
            animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
        }

        /* Safari */
        @-webkit-keyframes spin {
            0% {
                -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            }

            100% {
                -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
            }
        }

        @keyframes spin {
            0% {
                transform: rotate(0deg);
            }

            100% {
                transform: rotate(360deg);
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<center>
    <p style="font-size:400%">laden... </p>
    <div align="right">
        <div class="loader">
        </div>
    </div>
</center>
```

I tried putting the loader right of the text but that didn't work.
I just want that loader to be right of the message loading...

Comment: You are inconsistent in your usage of the closing `/` on the `<meta>` tag. But  note that the [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: I recommend you do several HTML&CSS tutorials before attempting anything specific. It can be quite unintuitive. For example a div is a block element which will start a new line, unless you change its styling. You can put the p tag in a div itself which is styled as an inline-block for example. But that is not the only solution.